# Pyplot of array with an operator < or >

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a function in Python with pyplot, where the problem could be boiled down to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x):
    if x<0:
        return x*x

interval = np.arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
plt.plot(interval, func(interval))
plt.show()
```

Which throws the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What would be the expected result of `func(np.arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1))`?

Comment: Aside: `nnb.__len__()` is a weird way to write `len(nnb)`.  No need for using the dunder method directly.

Comment: Please don't do such non-trivial edits that completly change the scope of the question after your question received (multiple) answers. That edit completly invalidated the existing answers. Just ask another question.

Comment: ok sry for the confusion

Comment: No problem. Feel free to share a link to your new question (you can find your new-old version in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44344542/revisions) if you want to copy it). I'll definetly take a look :)

Comment: here we go, new question is 44345357

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to change the values that are below zero you could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return np.where(x < 0, x*x, x)

print(func(np.arange(-4, 5)))  # array([16,  9,  4,  1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

If you just wanted the values below zero you could use [indexing with a boolean array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
def func(x):
    return x[x<0] ** 2 

print(func(np.arange(-4, 5)))  # array([16,  9,  4,  1])
```

---

More general: comparison operators on `numpy.array`s just return a boolean array:

```
>>> arr > 2
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> arr == 2
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

And the exception

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

happens when you do `bool(somearray)`. In a lot of cases the `bool()` call is implicit (so it may not be immediatly obvious to spot it). Examples of this implicit `bool()` call are `if`, `while`, `and` and `or`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> bool(arr)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> if arr: pass
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> while arr: pass
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> arr and arr
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> arr or arr
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In your case the `if x < 0` was the reason for the exception because `x < 0` returns a boolean array and then `if` tried to get the `bool()` of that array. Which as shown in the example above throws the exception you got.

Comment: Thx for the reply, I did just edit my question with the code of the actual function. I am still not sure how i might avoid the boolean array

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide what should happen to the values which are larger or equal to zero.

So let's assume you have the function

```
def func(x):
    if x<0:
        return x*x
    else:
        return 2*x
```

Now, something like `func(np.arange(-4,4,0.1))` will not work, because half the values of x are positive and half are negative. If you ask whether x is positive, the answer would be "it depends..". And that is what the error is telling you.

So you would need to make sure that the function treats the input array elementwise. To this end you may use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

```
func2 = np.vectorize(func)
interval = np.arange(-4.0,4.0,0.1)
plt.plot(interval, func2(interval))
```

which then plots the desired result.

You could also decide to directly write a function, which accepts an array as input. The example from above could then look like

```
def func3(x):
    return x*x*(x<0) + 2*x*(x>=0)
```